# Combine csv-files by columns with awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have several csv-files that I want to **combine columnwise**, i.e. content of each files should be appended as a new column (not in new lines).
I only need the content beginning with line 3 (which I solved with `FNR>2`) and column 1-3 in the order 1,3,2 (which I do with `print $1,$3,$2`). However, the files may contain a different number of lines for each column.

`file 1.csv`

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
Heading1;Heading2;Heading3;Heading4
11;12;13;useless
21;22;23;useless
31;32;33;useless
```

`file 2`

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
Heading1;Heading2;Heading3;Heading4
11;12;13;useless
21;22;23;useless
31;32;33;useless
41;42;43;useless
```

the output should be:

```
Heading1;Heading3;Heading2;Heading1;Heading3;Heading2
11;13;12;11;13;12
21;23;22;21;23;22
31;33;32;31;33;32
;;;41;43;42
```

This, of course, gives me the desired output, but with each output appended as a new line:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS = ";"} FNR>2 {print $1,$3,$2}' path/to/files/*csv
```

this appends columns, but does, of course, not insert any new lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS = ";"} FNR>2 {printf "%s%s%s%s%s", $1,OFS,$3,OFS,$2}' path/to/files/*csv
```

and this  is the same as my above command with `print`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS = ";"} FNR>2 {printf "%s%s%s%s%s", $1,OFS,$3,OFS,$2"\n"}' path/to/files/*csv
```

Thanks already for your suggestions!

Comment: Your output doesn't look in form of `$1 $3 $2` please be more clear in your question.

Comment: You are right, that was a mistake. I just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
FNR==1 { numFiles++ }
{ rowNr = FNR - 2 }
rowNr > 0 {
    rows[rowNr,numFiles] = $0
    numRows = (numRows > rowNr ? numRows : rowNr)
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        sep = ""
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++) {
            split(rows[rowNr,fileNr],row)
            printf "%s", sep row[1] OFS row[3] OFS row[2]
            sep = OFS
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1.csv file2.csv
Heading1;Heading3;Heading2;Heading1;Heading3;Heading2
11;13;12;11;13;12
21;23;22;21;23;22
31;33;32;31;33;32
;;;41;43;42
```

With GNU awk you can use `ARGIND` instead of setting/using `numFiles`.

Comment: Thank you, it works! In order to cope with files containing ^M characters I inserted `sub(/\r/,"")` as line 5 of your code - it works, but do you think that's the best place to add it?

Comment: Since you're not using the 4th field of your input those control-Ms at the end of the line (ie part of the 4th field AFA awk is concerned) shouldn't matter but if they do then that sub() would be fine but if you're using GNU awk you could just set `RS="\r?\n"` in the BEGIN section and it'll work either way. You could of course instead run `dos2unix` or similar on your input file before calling awk.